# need to get the active record in a custom format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Need that the active record should be in group or batch of two record.

Because i needs to loop the active record in group of twos.

currently i am getting all the data in format like for example

```
[#<users id: 2, title: "mr">,
 #<users id: 3, title: "mr">,
 #<users id: 4, title: "mr">,
 #<users id: 5, title: "mr">]
```

I the data like this,

```
[
    [#<users id: 2, title: "mr">, #<users id: 3, title: "mr">],
    [#<users id: 4, title: "mr">, #<users id: 5, title: "mr">]
]
```

This can be done by looping and push the data and create arrays manually, but I need it to be done by ActiveRecord.

Comment: Why do you need ActiveRecord to retrieve your data like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ActiveRecord has a [`find_in_batches`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-in-batches) method that will let you process table results in small groups instead of retrieving all the records from the database at once, but it sounds like you just want to avoid having to write loops to group your records into the array format that you want.

If that is the case, you can actually do that easily using the [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method:

```
User.all.each_slice(2).to_a
```

Comment: This not what i wants. Np i have find my self each_slice(2) method of array.

Comment: Ohhh, you're right, `each_cons` will give you duplicates. I'll update my answer to use `each_slice` instead.